# When to return tensors instead of values in Blazeface

Tags: tensorflow.js

In the Blazeface demo code and the `BlazeFaceModel` class, there is a parameter

```
@param returnTensors (defaults to `false`) Whether to return tensors as
   * opposed to values
```

This parameter is set to `false` in the demo. When should I want to return tensors instead of values for the Blazeface functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event that you want to use the tensors in another model. For example if you wanted to use a model that worked on problems involving humans you would use BlazeFace to detect the human faces then do another classification task on those faces which are tensors returned from the BlazeFace model.